# Vue: Check for changes in sessionStorage

Tags: vuejs2, axios

**Goal:** Check for existing sessionStorage data, fetch with Axios if it doesn't exist.

**Current State:** I successfully get the data, however, I have to navigate to another page, then back to the page the code is on to display it.

**Current Code:**

```
import Hero from "@/components/Hero.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "About",
  components: {
    Hero
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      eatery: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadEatery: function() {
      console.log("Fetching Data");
      axios
        .get(
          "//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=5&categories=2"
        )
        .then(response => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("eatery", JSON.stringify(response.data));
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error); // for debugging maybe
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("eatery")) {
      this.eatery = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("eatery"));
    } else {
      console.log("No Data Found");
      this.loadEatery().then(data => (this.eatery = data));
    }
  }
};
```

**Current Errors**
In console:

`[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle it is, set your this.eatery, as soon as you get the axios response. So instead of handling promise and callbacks here, do as:

```
loadEatery: function() {
  axios
    .get(
      "//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=5&categories=2"
    )
    .then(response => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("eatery", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      this.eatery = response.data // ADD THIS LINE TO DIRECTLY CHANGE
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error); // for debugging maybe
    });
}
```

And simply call, this.loadEatery();

Comment: This got me going when calling only `this.loadEatery();` inside of the else statement under mounted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you return `response.data` from your axios call, but you're only returning it into the context of the `loadEntry` function. Your `loadEntry` function does not return anything.

Try returning `response.data` from `loadEntry`:

```
loadEatery: function() {
  console.log("Fetching Data");
  let returnVal;

  axios
    .get(
      "//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=5&categories=2"
    )
    .then(response => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("eatery", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      returnVal = response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error); // for debugging maybe
    });

  return returnVal;
}
```

Or use async/await:

```
loadEatery: async function() {
  console.log("Fetching Data");

  const returnVal = await axios.get(
      "//localhost:81/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=5&categories=2"
    )
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error); // for debugging maybe
    });

  sessionStorage.setItem("eatery", JSON.stringify(response.data));
  return returnVal.data;
}
```